# Python: Pulling data using URL giving JSONDcodeError

Tags: python, json, url, python-requests

I am trying to pull transactions for a list of addresses:

```
wallet_addresses = ['0x7abe0ce388281d2acf297cb089caef3819b13448', '0xC098B2a3Aa256D2140208C3de6543aAEf5cd3A94',
                '0x2FAF487A4414Fe77e2327F0bf4AE2a264a776AD2']


for address in wallet_addresses:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)' 'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'https://etherscan.io/address/{address}#tokentxns'
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    result = response.json()
    print(result)
```

However, the above gives the following error:

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`

How can I get the contents of the page for each address?

EDIT: What I am hoping for is a json of the table contents on the page to convert to a DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to convert the server's response into json, but it's not json. Try getting the raw content instead:

```
...
result = response.content
print(content)
```

etherscan.io [has an API](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts), which should return the same data in a more easily consumable JSON format

Comment: That worked but gives raw data. What I was hoping for is some sort of json format to convert to a DataFrame. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MathMan99 Updated my answer re your Q